# How to access POST parameters when validation failed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I need to show the response page depending on some of the input fields. E.g. the tabid inputHidden below:

```
#{controllerBean.tabId}
...
<h:form id="edit">
  <h:inputHidden value="#{controllerBean.tabId}" id="tabid" />
  <h:inputText value="#{controllerBean.name}" id="name" />
</h:form>
```

But when some other input in the same form has validation error (e.g. the "name" inputText). The "controllerBean.tabId" value will not be assigned because JSF returns at validation stage.

I still need the tabId to show the page correctly and having 2 ideas in mind:

```
#{param['edit:tabid']}
```

or use binding:

```
#{tabId.value}
<h:inputHidden value="#{controllerBean.tabId}" id="tabid" binding="tabId" />
```

My question is, which of these 2 is the better or Best Practice? Or there are even better ways to do this?

---

update:

Note. In my specific case, the tabid is set by client javascript.

1. Server reply with a few items in the html.
2. Javascript put these items into different tabs on the page.
3. One of the tabs POST data to server with the current tabid in the form.

So my server need to know the tabid to show the response page with the correct tab selected.

Comment: but where do you need it in the managedBean but if the validation error occures your managed bean will not be invoked.

Comment: It's not my bean needs it but my page. Specifically, my page needs the tabid to know which tab to be showed

Comment: Do you have the chance of going with `@ViewScoped`? That would allow you keeping current tab id in the bean.

Comment: The tabid is specified by client javascript, so the original page does not have it. I think view scope does not help either(without using ajax) :( Updated the question with my specific case.

Comment: Do you need `tabId` for other purposes in the bean? Or do you solely have a property+getter+setter which is *nowhere* else in the bean used during e.g. actions?

Comment: Balus, till now I don't see other usage of the tabId, it's only sent back to browser to show the correct tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [lifecycle event listener](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) to the component and pick the value from it. I'm going to recommend the `preValidate` listener:

```
 <h:form id="edit">
     <h:inputHidden value="#{controllerBean.tabId}" id="tabid">
         <f:event type="preValidate" listener="#{controller.grabTabId}"/>
     </h:inputHidden>
     <h:inputText value="#{controllerBean.name}" id="name" />
 </h:form>
```

This registers the listener to fire just before the validation phase of the request. You'll now have a listener defined in your backing bean to look like:

```
   public void grabTabId(ComponentSystemEvent cse){
     //obtain a reference to the component
     HtmlInputHidden hiddenElement = (HtmlInputHidden)cse.getComponent(); 
     //get the value from the component.
     String hiddenValue = hiddenElement.getValue();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:form id="edit">
 <h:inputHidden value="#{controllerBean.tabId}" id="tabid" />
 <h:inputText value="#{controllerBean.name}" id="name" >
  <p:ajax process="tabid" immediate="true" event="keyup" />
 </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

The above code will do is when the user put some value the value will be processed and will be set the managedBean. that what you want I think.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. My controllerBean is requestScoped, I think the ajax way will not work?

Comment: @Kai then use `@ViewScoped` at least. And I won't recommend using ajax per keyup, it could be a lot of request per new char in a text.

Comment: The tabid is specified by client javascript, and the original page does not have it. So I think view scope does not help either(without using ajax) :( Updated the question with my specific case

Answer (score 0):

Another non-perfect way of accomplishing this is to move the validation logic to your action method.  If validation fails, you just stop processing (and add an applicable FacesMessage).  You just need to be aware that **all** model values will have been updated, and you can clear them if necessary.

Since updating model values on failed validation goes against the JSF lifecycle, I think any solution will be somewhat of a hack.